# Защита окружения lua при загрузке модуля (sandboxing)

Tags: lua

Мне хотелось бы безопасно загрузить недоверенный lua-модуль, который возвращает таблицу, так чтобы кроме таблицы от модуля не было никаких побочных эффектов - т.е. чтобы он не мог выполнить никаких функций и не имел возможности менять переменные в глобальной области видимости. Есть идеи как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lua
local file = 'conf.lua'
local func, err = loadfile(file)
if err then error(err) end
local succes, result = pcall(setfenv(func, {}))
if not succes then error(result) end
if type(result) ~= 'table' then
  error(file .. ' can only return a table')
end

for k, v in pairs(result) do print(k, v) end
```

Пример `conf.lua`:

```lua
-- VIRUS = 'я ничего не сделаю'
-- _G.VIRUS = 'я вызову ошибку'
-- print 'я тоже вызову ошибку'

A = 2+2 -- я НЕ глобальная переменная

return {
  a = A, -- так можно
  b = '456',
  c = function ()
    print 'я под карантином и не работаю,\
    пока мне не установят окружение,\
    вот так: setfenv(result.c, _G)'
  end
}
```